# find the curvature of $r(t)=(3\sin(t))i+(3\sin(t))j+(\cos(t))k$

Tags: calculus

Find the curvature $κ(t)$ of the curve $$r(t)=(3\sin(t))i+(3\sin(t))j+(\cos(t))k$$
I know curvature is
 $$\frac{\Vert r'(t)\times r''(t)\Vert}{\Vert r(t)\Vert^3}$$

Comment: Did you have trouble with any of the parts?

Comment: If thre are no typos $$ \| r'  \times  r''\|=\left|\begin{matrix}
i & j & k \\
3\cos t & 3\cos t & -\sin t \\
-3\sin t & -3\sin t & -\cos t
\end{matrix}\right| = $$
$$=\left|\begin{matrix}
3\cos t & -\sin t \\
-3\sin t & -\cos t
\end{matrix}\right| i- \left|\begin{matrix}
3\cos t & -\sin t \\
-3\sin t & -\cos t
\end{matrix}\right| j=-3i+3j+0k.$$ This is an exercise that you  are able to understand, see more exmaples in [Pauls Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Curvature.aspx). Tell the users what is that you don't know. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you must start by the derivatives:
$$r'(t)=3\cos(t)\vec{i}+3\cos(t)\vec{j}-\sin(t)\vec{k}$$
$$r''(t)=-3\sin(t)\vec{i}-3\sin(t)\vec{j}-\cos(t)\vec{k}$$
and now the crossproduct

Comment: There is a typo in $r''(t)$.

Comment: Shouldn't $-3\cos t \hat j$ be $-3\sin t \hat j$?

Comment: ok typo is corrected! thank you!